# proper method to identify a particular plant in the video when the taken video is fast?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, video-processing, detection

I am new to machine learning. I want to run a classifier (machine-learning-based or deep learning based) on the video to identify one Plant in a grass video.

I have some issues in the taken video:

1. The video is fast and sometimes it is even difficult for me to identify the plant in the video.
2. The resolution or video quality is very high (taken by camera RGB - 12 Mega Pixel)

What would be the best approach to identify this plant? what machine learning approach will provide a more accurate result?

Answer (score 0):

Every deep learning architecture takes frames for processing, so video is converted into frames, so it does not depend on video speed.
Accuracy depends on deep learning architecture.

you can check some deep learning architecture such as (YOLO and SSD).